# How can basicHttpBinding, webHttpBinding & mexHttpBinding endpoints coexist in one WCF service

Tags: wcf, mex, basichttpbinding, webhttpbinding

I have a WCF service (target .NET 4) and I need to expose 4 endpoints: SOAP, POX, JSON & MEX.

My configuration file looks like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <!-- bindings -->
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name ="soapBinding">
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webBinding">
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <!-- behaviors -->
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <!-- plain old XML -->
        <behavior name="poxBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
        <!-- JSON -->
        <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
          <enableWebScript  />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="defaultBehavior">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="PubtranService.Service" behaviorConfiguration="defaultBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://192.168.1.102:8080/PT/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint name="soap"
                  address="soap"
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="soapBinding"
                  contract="PubtranService.IService" />
        <endpoint name="pox"
                  address="pox"
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="webBinding"
                  behaviorConfiguration="poxBehavior"
                  contract="PubtranService.IService" />
        <endpoint name="json"
                  address="json"
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="webBinding"
                  behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior"
                  contract="PubtranService.IService" />
        <endpoint name="mex"
                  address="mex" 
                  binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration=""
                  contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

And when I run the service the WCF Test Client returns *failed to add service* msg with a `System.NullReferenceException` - *object reference not set to an instance of an object* and a stack trace:

```
System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataBehavior.MetadataExtensionInitializer.GenerateMetadata()
System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.EnsureInitialized()   System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.WSMexImpl.GatherMetadata(String dialect, String identifier)   System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.WSMexImpl.Get(Message request)
SyncInvokeGet(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&amp; outputs)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

But the JSON and POX endpoints are accessible and work just fine. 
On the other hand when I comment them out from the configuration the WCF Test Client properly shows the SOAP service.

At the moment there is only one simple method implemented in the service:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://192.168.1.102:8080/")]
public interface IService
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    Tram[] GetOverview(string id);

}
```

Why do I brake the mex endpoint by adding the pox and json endpoints?

Answer (score 3):

If your aim is to have 1 method to serve for both xml and json i could achieve it as shown below:

```
<service name ="XMLService.MultipleEndpointService">        
        <endpoint name="soap" address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="XMLService.IMultipleEndpointService" />
        <endpoint name="pox" address="pox" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="web" contract="XMLService.IMultipleEndpointService" />
        <endpoint name="mex" address="mex"  binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
</service>

<endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">          
      <webHttp/>          
    </behavior>        
 </endpointBehaviors>
```

Now in your class that implements the Interface i did the following:

```
public Tram[] GetOverview(string id)
        {
            IList<ContentType> acceptHeaderElements = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.GetAcceptHeaderElements();
            for (int x = 0; x < acceptHeaderElements.Count; x++)
            {
                string normalizedMediaType = acceptHeaderElements[x].MediaType.ToLowerInvariant();
                switch (normalizedMediaType)
                {
                    case "application/xml":
                        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Format = WebMessageFormat.Xml;
                        break;
                    case "application/json":
                        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Format = WebMessageFormat.Json;
                        break;
                }
            }

            return new[] { new Tram() { TramName = "Tram 1" }, new Tram() { TramName = "Tram 2" } };
        }
```

Now when i perform a get on the above service using Fiddler :

```
GET http://localhost/XMLService/multipleendpointservice.svc/pox/GetOverview HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost
Accept: application/json
```

My response is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 79
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 30 Nov 2011 11:39:16 GMT

[{"<TramName>k__BackingField":"Tram 1"},{"<TramName>k__BackingField":"Tram 2"}]
```

Similarly when i perform :

```
GET http://localhost/XMLService/multipleendpointservice.svc/pox/GetOverview HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost
Accept: application/xml
```

My response is :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 334
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 30 Nov 2011 11:39:09 GMT

<ArrayOfTram xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XMLService" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Tram><_x003C_TramName_x003E_k__BackingField>Tram 1</_x003C_TramName_x003E_k__BackingField></Tram><Tram><_x003C_TramName_x003E_k__BackingField>Tram 2</_x003C_TramName_x003E_k__BackingField></Tram></ArrayOfTram>
```

NOTE: The Accept header can be other than application/xml or application/json. in such cases you need to handle it.

The other alternative is to use the WebServiceHostFactory and use the [webHttpEndpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee476510.aspx) element that has the automaticFormatSelection attribute to perform the above action

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the XML and JSON endpoints are working just fine, without even a line of code in the service interface - the response type is correctly determined automatically.

My question is why does the mex endpoint stop to work when I add the json and pox ones.

Comment: I think we cannot have both Json and Xml endpoint using the webHttpbinding as you havent specified your response/request type in the [WebGet] attribute. Just remove either of the one and you can see your soap and rest service would start working as expected. I think it must be due to the ServiceHostFactory that is being used by the webHttpBinding

Comment: Json and Xml _are_ working at the same time just fine. But if I add at least one XML or JSON the SOAP one stops to work.

Comment: Are you running the above using .NET 4.0 framework. Using .NET 3.5 hosted on IIS everything works without any errors. Access to SOAP, POX, JSON endpoints doesnt throw any errors. Seems like a problem with the .NET 4 framework. I have posted this as a bug on the Microsoft connect site just if you can vote it would be fixed in the coming release hopefully. The link is https://connect.microsoft.com/wcf/feedback/details/711802/hosting-multiple-endpoints-soap-xml-and-json-causes-an-exception-when-accessing-the-service#tabs

Answer (score 0):

Well, simple duplication of the binding configuration `webBinding` with different name `webBinding2` would allow to expose metadata.
At least I tried it out and it worked, though it is weird that WCF behaves this way.

```
    <endpoint name="pox"
              address="pox"
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="webBinding"
              behaviorConfiguration="poxBehavior"
              contract="PubtranService.IService" />
    <endpoint name="json"
              address="json"
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="webBinding2"
              behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior"
              contract="PubtranService.IService" />
```